# Getting "AllDay" for every calendar i create in Google apps using .NET google API Ver 2

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I am creating a calendar in google calendar using Google API ver 2.
Problem i am facing is:

I am getting all calendar as "ALLDAY".

I tried below code:

```
When eventTime = new When();
eventTime.AllDay = false;
entry.Times.Add(eventTime); // i am not setting dates as i am assigning them in recurrance data.
```

How to make all day event to false?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a recurrent event, I don't think you should be adding a "When" element at all. What happens if you try the [sample recurrent event code from the docs](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#CreatingRecurring)?

What does your recurrence data look like?

Comment: when i send recurrence data as specified by example ( on link given by you). Resultant event is "all day".But i don't want "all day" event.
What should i do in that case?

Comment: @Pari: That recurrence is for a date rather than a date and time. If you want a non-all day recurrent event, you need to specify its time within the recurrence rule.